# Removing a string from a std::vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a `std::vector<string>` called `v`. I'd like to read in a string from the user and remove it from `v`. Here's what I have so far:

```
string rnames;
cout << "Enter the string to remove " << endl;
cin >> rnames;

v.erase(rnames);
```

This produces an error.

Any ideas how we can make this to work? Do we first need to find the rnames and then erase it?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? How is the vector declared?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

Comment: vector was declared as : vector<string> names;

Comment: @RetiredNinja My suspicion is that OP hasn't seen the general pattern for how to do this before, so the documentation, while complete and accurate, might not be all that useful without a bigger-picture view of what's going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `std::vector`'s `erase` method takes in an iterator saying which entry in the vector you want to remove. It doesn't work like the map or set where you can call `erase` to remove a specified key.

To remove a single copy of an element from a `std::vector`, you can use `std::find` and the `std::vector`'s `erase` member function like this:

```
auto itr = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), rnames);
if (itr != v.end()) v.erase(itr);
```

The above code assumes you're using C++11, which all major modern compilers support. However, it seems like you're using an older compiler that doesn't support C++11, so you'd have to write something like this:

```
std::vector<string>::iterator itr = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), rnames);
if (itr != v.end()) v.erase(itr);
```

To remove *all* copies of an element from a `vector`, you can use `std::remove` like this:

```
v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), rnames), v.end());
```

(This requires the `<algorithm>` header.) That being said, if you find that you are often removing elements from a `std::vector` and you have a large number of elements in the vector, you may want to consider changing data structures to something that more efficiently supports removals.

Comment: That's awesome, I now get an error saying itr does not name a type and itr was not declared in this scope.

Comment: What compiler are you using? The `auto` feature is a C++11 feature, and the error you're describing sounds like you might be using an older compiler.

Comment: I am using the compiler DEV C++

Comment: @fsfh60 Oh wow, that's an old compiler. You should really consider getting a newer one. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hello again I am now getting a different I am using namespace std; in the header. [Error] no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::string&)'

Comment: Have you included the <algorithm> header?

Comment: You sir are a legend in the game. I appreciate you.

Comment: For the solution with std::remove to work, one needs to have #include <algorithm> otherwise there would be error: error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>::iterator …' to 'const char* for argument '1' …' on my Ubuntu 16.04